# MVC Save data from two models in one view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, code-first

Hi I have spent hours trying to work out how to do this one.

So lets say I have two models:

model 1 - AccountInformation

model 2 - AccountHoldersImages

One account holder can have many images.  I am trying to achieve on the accountInformation create view (using Scaffolding) to include the facility to add the images at the same time of creation of the user account.  Is this possible?

Comment: Hard to say with just what you shared, but I would have a third model that _wraps_ these other two.

Comment: yes it is possible by ViewModel (view specific model) as told by @MelanciaUK

Comment: Ok thanks I have tried that but can't get the model to find the fields in the create view (e.g. model => model.dateofbirth). I don't expect you to write up a whole solution for me as I am sure you have better things to do but could you point in the direction of any tutorials for this, would be great.  Thanks

Comment: please refer this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/687061/Multiple-Models-in-a-View-in-ASP-NET-MVC-MVC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> One account holder can have many images

In which case, AccountHoldersImages must be a part of AccountInformation.

If in different views you are using AccountHoldersImages separately, then may be you can keep the view models separate.

However, for this particular view that you are talking about, you will have to wrap the view models into a single view model as MelancialUK commented above.

Another way is to pass the models as part of ViewData[]. If it is a form, then on post you can use FormCollection parameter of your [HttpPost] action to get your images.